# Error in FQL Query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

This is My Code

```
$ids = join(", ",$man);

    if ( !isset($_SESSION[$appID.'_FQLResult']) ) {



        $FQLQuery = "SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in ($ids)";



        $FQLResult = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $FQLQuery, 'access_token'=>$fbme['access_token'] ));
        $_SESSION[$appID.'_FQLResult'] = $FQLResult;
    } else {
        $FQLResult = $_SESSION[$appID.'_FQLResult'];
    }
echo $ids;
echo $FQLResult;
```

There is an error
when i echo $ids it shows the value of $ids but when i echo $FQLResult is shows only "array" written whats wrong in this fql query?
how i can fix this?
I think there is something wrong in this query
 $FQLQuery = "SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in ($ids)";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) directly instead of [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)
2. After a successful API call, you should be expecting an array, so use `print_r($FQLResult);`
3. Always, if you are not sure of the type of the variable use `var_dump()`
4. You may want to use the new Graph API end-point (`/fql?q=YOUR_QUERY`), read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/)
5. Serialize your array before adding to sessions
6. Watch our of the session size limits!